# Direct download of Bootcamp driver 6.1 for windows 10?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver

Hi my macbook is a late 2013 15inch model. I just did a clean installation of Windows 10 ver 1607 (anniversary edition). It is the only partition on my macbook. So I don't have any access to OSX. Now I need to install the driver package, but I couldn't find it anywhere on apple support page. Is there a direct download link for the drivers? Thanks!

Update:

1. I don't have any OSX partition on my pc.
2. I don't need to read any HFS+ file system. That file system is buggy like hell.
3. The issue has been solved by installing OSX on a flash drive and run bootcamp assistant to download the drivers. Now my Windows 10 drive is running without any problem. And I was able to read the HFS+ partition on the flash drive. So this is not a bug for me.

Comment: At the present time, Boot Camp Support Software version 6.x is only available from within Boot Camp Assistant. Apple has yet to provide a direct download link.

Answer (score 14):

just use https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier
found it on discussions apple forum
look for the LonerT's post Aug 25, 2015 7:24 PM in response to dioshy (quoting everything from there even though 2012 model is not your case but the solution still stands)

"1. Please see BootCamp 6 update not available on MacBook Pro mid 2012 with Windows 10 for the two methods supported by Apple to get BC6 drivers.

2. You can manually download BC6 drivers from Apple CDN using Brigadier (https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier) by specifying your model number available from How to identify MacBook Pro models - Apple Support .
3. Please also see Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp - Apple Support."
   As a result you can get all of the Bootcamp packages for your/other macs.

Comment: This is interesting, however it doesn't download the correct package for my 2013 MBP.

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. @user3439894: you can specify the model of your computer and the package you want with the arguments to Brigadier.

Comment: Doesn't work so well for Bootcamp 6. There's now a comment in the ReadMe.md for this repository that states that. I've run into problems trying to get it to work myself.

Comment: How does this work if the mac is enrolled in the Remote Management program?

Comment: Any idea where one might find step by step instructions on using brigadier on an iMac? Do you load python on the iMac?  All the instructions are for Windows which makes no sense or am i missing something? Confused (I wish they would just fix BootCamp Assistant and make it compatible with the last 3 releases of Win 10 !)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running El Capitan (OS X 10.11), you can download the Boot Camp Support Software by following the steps given below.

1. Open the Boot Camp Assistant application.
2. Selelct "Action" on the Menu Bar.
3. Select "Download Windows Support Software".

Apple officially supports Windows 10 on the newer Macs. Generally these are the 2012 and later models. The originally released version of Windows 10 was number 1511. The Windows version can be determined by opening a Command Prompt window and entering the command `winver`. Below is example.

[image]

For version 1511, read only access to HFS+ formatted partitions can be enabled by installing the Boot Camp Support Software.

Recently, Microsoft has released a new version numbered 1607. This is referred to as the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. This version has a bug that can prevent read only access to HFS formatted volumes. Here is a [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7629103?start=0&tstart=0) to an Apple Communities web site that also confirms this bug exists. **Therefore, if you using version 1601 of Windows 10, you many not be able to access HFS formatted volumes even if you have installed the Boot Camp Support Software.** Until this bug is fixed, users will have to use version 1511 or find another way copy data from HFS formatted volumes.

Paragon Software offers [drivers](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) that allow read/write access to HFS+ file systems. They offer a 10 day trial period for you test the drivers. I have not done this. So I do not know if the bug also affects their drivers. Another alternative would be to allow OS X to read/write to NTFS formatted volumes. Again, Paragon Software offers this [software](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) for OS X.

Comment: no joy since bootCamp assistant can't format any thumbdrive on the market (tried 8 brands - no joy)

Comment: Yesterday, I used the Boot Camp Assistant from Catalina on a 2013 iMac to create a Windows 10 installer thumb drive. You must be making some sort of simple mistake.

Comment: @MC9000, you need to use the command line instead of Disk Utility to format the drive correctly. See the answer here: How do I pass the following error message in the Boot Camp Assistant: “Please format the USB drive as single FAT partition.”?: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232993/how-do-i-pass-the-following-error-message-in-the-boot-camp-assistant-please-fo/232996#232996](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232993/how-do-i-pass-the-following-error-message-in-the-boot-camp-assistant-please-fo/232996#232996)

Comment: It turns out that you must use an older version/ISO of Win10 - I used 1703 and it worked.  BCA won't work with later versions.  (20H2, for example) The only way to do this is use a 17xx version or earlier, then upgrade your win10 OS.

Comment: You an install the current Windows 10 on most Macs without using the BCA. However, sometimes the procedure can be quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have got an alternate fix, with the use of Brigadier,
that downloads BootCamp 6.0 for my MacBookPro9,1 [mid-2012],
and 6.1 supports the APFS-boot-to-mac-functionality.

First install the version that won't support all keys on ancient macbooks,
with Brigadier -m iMac19,1
Then you will have in your Download folder a BootCamp 6.1 install directory,

Then follow the next steps, after removing that installation and KEEP the install directory.

1. Run M$Program Install and Uninstall to kill BootCamp Services and/or Apple Software Update
2. Run BootCamp 6.0 [eg. Brigadier -m MacBookPro9,1]
3. If not extracted, extract 'BootCamp.msi' from BootCamp 061-97204,
   This contains working versions of the controlPanel,
   that when simply replaced in System32
   [3 files from the extracted BootCamp.msi from the 061 directory, and ProgramFiles\BootCamp with only bootcamp.exe and lang-support files. Those are actually still fine.]
   allow actual APFS-BootVolume recognition.
   keep in mind, that the copy might be prevented by a still running service.
4. Reboot

This took me a while to reproduce again, after I got it working a few months ago,
that enabled that non-holding-keys reboot from windows [gaming] to normal Mac Catalina.

Therefore, also for my future reference ;-]

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the versions of Boot Camp and download them for free from this page.
You can find the version of Boot Camp you need according to your Mac model and Windows version.

https://www.applex.net/pages/bootcamp/

Comment: That is not an official Apple site - how do we know the downloads don't have malware